# Rusty describes his needs for an 11 man crew

Tags: plot-explanation, oceans-eleven

In Ocean's Eleven, Rusty (Brad Pitt) and Danny Ocean (Gorge Clooney) are in the architect firm's building that designed the vault of the Ballagio Casino, Las Vegas at night going over the blueprints. Then Danny asks what does Rusty think about it. Rusty says he's looking for guys, and I quote, "Off the top of my head, I'd say you're looking at a Boesky, a Jim Brown, a Miss Daisy, two Jethros and a Leon Spinks, not to mention the biggest Ella Fitzgerald ever." What does he mean by this statement?